# Get rows from one df based on lookup df matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframe. One(DF1) contains data about the actual "type" of information in each Name and the second(DF2) contains what "type" is present in the Name. DF2 will not contain all the Names from DF1.  Need to return a Dataframe with rows from DF1 that satisfy from the DF2.

For example,
 DF1:

```
       Name      type(uuid)           start         letter     etc..
    0  2         a_1                  011           H
    1  2         a_3                  012           I
    2  1         a_2                  203           K
    3  4         a_1                  943           P
    4  5         a_3                  925           L
```

DF2 a lookup matrix:

```
       Name      a_1    a_2     a_3    a_n
    0  1         0       1       0      0 
    1  2         1       0       1      0 
    2  3         0       0       0      0
```

DF2 is a result matrix from a train/test split. Hence does not contain the full dataset. Based on the Names in the df I need to pick rows from DF1.

Would need to output dataframe.

DF Type A:

```
       Name      type           start         letter
    0  2         a_1            011           H
    1  2         a_3            012           I
    2  1         a_2            203           K
```

I have tried using masks for this. But it doesn't seem like the most efficient way of doing it. I am pretty new to using pandas and feel like there would be a better way to do this.
What I have tried:

```py
type = df_two.columns.values

for name in df_two.index.tolist():
    mask = df_one.type.apply(lambda x: any(item for item in type if item in x))

    mask_doc = (df_one['Name'].values == name) & (mask)

    temp = df_one[mask_doc]
```

This gives me a separate dataframe for each Name and I have to merge them later. Its pretty slow.

Is there a better/efficient approach to do this in pandas?

Edit: The values for a_1,..,a_n are actually uuid's in my dataset.

Edit 2: Was trying to generalize the question far too much. Cleaned it up to the essential problem.

Comment: if they are uuid's? how would you split them between type a and type b?

Comment: Fair point. I had a mapping of UUID to type which I was using to select just those columns from DF2. Then ran into the main issue. Initially I was trying to generalize the problem way too much. Updated the question to the main problem I'm facing.

Comment: UUID's are generally unique. Are all the values in type column unique or can they repeat? because `a_1` appears twice in your example.

Comment: @RithinChalumuri The uuid is a reference from another db table. The Name and type are not one - one. This DF simply says DocumentName has label of type(uuid) and the required information about the label (letter, start, etc..). So they could repeat!

Comment: Why is index `0,1,2` in your expected ouput dataframe and not index `3,4`. What's the correlation between your input and expected outframes?

Comment: Index 3, 4 are not part of DF2, hence they are not included. DF2 is a result of doing train/test split so I only get 80% of data and is not a complete set.

Answer (score 0):

If lookup is really necessary, then you can use unstack to get a multi-indexed item. Then by filtering and right joining df1 on unstacked df2, you will get the result.

```
result = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(df2.unstack()), df1, left_index=True, right_on=['type', 'name'], how='left')
```

Then select the columns you need.

Comment: Just realized I would get a similar response while re-reading the question. Added an edit to the question. The types are actually uuid values in my dataset.

Comment: @JayPatel what is uuid? like subgroups in a larger group? In that case you have a dictionary mapping from groupname to subgroups?

Comment: Will test it out as soon as i get a chance. Will update!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

First, create Dataframe to use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df2_mapper=df2.set_index('Name')
```

---

then map using [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to create an additional column with about 1 and 0. Then simply select only the rows with value 1

```
df_filter=df1.copy()
df_filter['filter']=df2_mapper.lookup(df1['Name'],df1['type'])
df_filter=df_filter[df_filter['filter'].eq(1)]
print(df_filter)
   Name type  start letter  filter
0     2  a_1     11      H       1
1     2  a_3     12      I       1
2     1  a_2    203      K       1
3     2  b_1    943      P       1
4     5  b_3    925      L       1
```

---

Finally I thought that there could be more than two types and therefore I decided to propose that you create a dataframe dictionary. Where each dataframe corresponds to a type.

```
groups=df_filter['type'].str.replace('(\d+)','').str.replace('_','')
df_types={i:group.reindex(columns=df1.columns) for i, group in df_filter.groupby(groups)}
```

---

**showing and accessing the dataframe of the dictionary**

```
for _type in df_types:
    print(f'df_types[{_type}]')
    print(df_types[_type])
    print('-'*20)
```

**Output**

```
df_types[a]
   Name type  start letter
0     2  a_1     11      H
1     2  a_3     12      I
2     1  a_2    203      K
--------------------
df_types[b]
   Name type  start letter
3     2  b_1    943      P
4     5  b_3    925      L
--------------------
```

## if the number of types is only two you can simply do:

```
# Creanting mapper
df2_mapper=df2.set_index('Name')
#Mapping and filtering
df_filter=df1.copy()
df_filter['filter']=df2_mapper.lookup(df1['Name'],df1['type'])
df_filter=df_filter[df_filter['filter'].eq(1)]
#Creating df_A and df_B
mask_A=df_filter['type'].str.contains('a')
df_type=df_filter.reindex(columns=df1.columns)
df_A=df_type[mask_A]
df_B=df_type[~mask_A]
```

Comment: Perfect:) I hope your comment